# Acces Model-function from inside the model

Tags: php, model, laravel, laravel-4

I'm pretty new to Laravel and am struggeling with the following problem at the moment:

I want to create a User-Group-Management. So I want to add Users to a Group and add Rights to these Groups, to have an authorization. My aim is to have a `User::hasRight('exampleRight')` function, which i can easily call. For that I wanted to have a function chaining inside of the User-Class. I have this function to create a Connection to the UserGroup-Table (which connects an User-ID to a Group-ID):

```
public function role()
{
return $this->hasOne('UserGroup');
}
```

The next function shall return an Array of rights. My plan was to write something like

```
public function rights()
{
$rights = Groups::find($this->role()->groups_id)->rights;
return $rights;
}
```

The GroupsModel of course has this function to get the Rights:

```
public function rights()
{
return $this->hasMany('Rights');
}
```

But obviously `$this->role()->groups_id` doesn't give me the groups_id but instead throws the Error `Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasOne::$groups_id`. When i leave the `->groups_id` out, and do add it instead in the controller like:

(Attention Controller, no model!)

```
public function getUserRole()
{
return User::find(10)->rights->groups_id;
}
```

it gives me the right answer. Can somebody tell me, whats the error? I don't really get whats wrong...

Thanks you in advance!

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this particular method you need to remove the parenthesis:

```
public function rights()
{
    $rights = Groups::find($this->role->groups_id)->rights;
    return $rights;
}
```

When you do `role()` you're actually telling Laravel to return the relation object, so you can do things like

```
$this->role()->where('x', '=', 'y')->get();
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer. Unfortunatly I get this Error, when doing it this way: `Call to a member function getResults() on a non-object`, probably becuase `$this->role()` does not return an Array, but an JSON-String like `{"id":2,"user_id":10,"groups_id":1}`. Is there something I am missing?

Comment: Laravel handles that for you. You have first to be sure that `$this->role->groups_id` returns somethig and ID that exists in the Groups table, if it doesn't that `->rights` will give you an error.

Comment: Well, if I fire `User::find(10)->role->groups_id;` in a controller, it returns me the right information. If I do `$this->role->groups_id` in the model, I get the Error above...

Comment: Ok, somehow I must've been somekind of stupid. It worked your way :) I must have done something stupid. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Why do you have an intermediary table between User and Group? Simply give the User a group_id. Here is how I have built this in the past.

> User belongsTo Group
>
> Group belongsToMany Right

```
// Inside User Model
public function can($name)
{
    foreach ($this->group->rights as $right)
    {
        if ($right->name == $name)
        {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}

// Elsewhere
if (!$user->can('edit_blogs'))
{
    return 'FORBIDDEN';
}
```

- Look into eager loading to mitigate performance issues.
- Look into filters to apply these access restrictions at the controller or route level.

Comment: First, thanks for your help. This is actually a pretty straight way and I would love to do it that way, but unfortunatly, the database structure is specified that way. So I cannot change it that easy. I think the system, I'm builing my App on, assumes that one User has multiple roles...